# Powershell - Sequential foreach loop zipping files

Tags: windows, powershell, winrar

I have a number of IIS servers, each with a number of sites on them and I want to zip all IIS logs regularly.

I cobbled together the following powershell script with the help of this site and google:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem  "D:\logfiles\IIS-Logs\*.log" -Recurse | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7))} 
foreach ($file in $files) {& 'C:\Program Files\WinRAR\winrar.exe' a -tl -df -m5 "$file.rar" $File}
```

The problem with this script is that if there are.. say... 2,000 total log files it tried to launch 2,000 simultaneous copies of Winrar and the server will crash. This was unexpected. I expected it to zip the files one at a time. Sequentially.

Does anyone have any ideas to make this work like I want?

I'd really like to use Winrar vs the native Compress-Archive option because:

- I want the file dates to reflect the zipped file, not the date it was zipped.
- I want the utility to delete the files after archiving because the utility will not delete the file if the archiving failed.

I'm not married to Winrar if I can achieve this another way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use "Start-Process -Wait" instead of using the &. Using the -Wait flag on Start-Process forces it to wait for completion, and will then cause your program to run sequentially. Check this article on how to use Start-Process: A Better PowerShell Start Process You might also want to use the cmdlet Compress-Archive instead of the command line program Winrar, which might be better integrated and give you better feedback in your scripting.

Something like this with WinRAR?

```
$files = Get-ChildItem  "D:\logfiles\IIS-Logs\*.log" -Recurse | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7))}
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $args = 'a -tl -df -m5 "' + $file.rar + '" ' + $File
    Start-Process -Wait -filepath 'C:\Program Files\WinRAR\winrar.exe' -ArgumentList $args
}
```

Or this with Compress-Archive

```
$files = Get-ChildItem  "D:\logfiles\IIS-Logs\*.log" -Recurse | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7))}
foreach ($file in $files) {
    Compress-Archive -Path $file.FullName -DestinationPath "$($File.FullName).rar"
{
```

The above are untested, but should work unless I made a typo.

Comment: The $args were incorrect making the rar name blank... but with a few tweaks, this is working brilliantly with winrar! Thanks ($args = 'a -tl -df -m5 ' + $file +'.rar ' + $File)

Comment: Yeah, the syntax of passing args to non-powershell aware programs/processes is a bit wonky.  Glad you were able to get it to work though!

Answer (score 1):

For testing purpose, i created a LogFolder with 3 separate log folders, Log1, Log2 and Log3. Each of these Log folders have 2000 files with 2MB data each. This is the command i ran to Compress each folder `seperately

You can also run these in serial if the performance is too slow (when reading from same disk and writing to same as well).

```
$ElementsInLog = (Get-ChildItem C:\temp\LogFolder\*.txt -Recurse).Length
$ElementsInLog1 = (Get-ChildItem C:\temp\LogFolder\Log1\*.txt -Recurse).Length
$ElementsInLog2 = (Get-ChildItem C:\temp\LogFolder\Log2\*.txt -Recurse).Length
$ElementsInLog3 = (Get-ChildItem C:\temp\LogFolder\Log3\*.txt -Recurse).Length

Write-Output "Main: $ElementsInLog`nLog1: $ElementsInLog1`nLog2: $elementsInLog2`nLog3: $elementsInLog3"
Write-output "Total File Size: $((Get-ChildItem C:\temp\LogFolder\Log1\*.txt -Recurse | Measure-Object length -Sum).Sum / 1024 / 1024 / 1024) GB"


Write-Output "Starting Tasks..."

$job1 = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
  Write-Output "Log1: $(Get-Date -Format G)"
  Get-ChildItem C:\temp\LogFolder\Log1 -Recurse | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath C:\temp\log1.zip -CompressionLevel Fastest
  Write-Output "Finished: $(Get-Date -Format G)"
}

$job2 = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    Write-Output "Log2: $(Get-Date -Format G)"
    Get-ChildItem C:\temp\LogFolder\Log3 -Recurse | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath C:\temp\log3.zip -CompressionLevel Fastest
    Write-Output "Finished: $(Get-Date -Format G)"
}

$job3 = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    Write-Output "Log2: $(Get-Date -Format G)"
    Get-ChildItem C:\temp\LogFolder\Log4 | Compress-Archive -DestinationPath C:\temp\log4.zip -CompressionLevel Fastest
    Write-Output "Finished: $(Get-Date -Format G)"
}

while($job1.State -eq "Running" -or $job2.State -eq "Running" -or $job3.State -eq "Running") { 
    Start-Sleep 5
}

Receive-Job $job1
Receive-Job $job2
Receive-Job $job3
```

**Output Received**

```
Main: 8000
Log1: 2000
Log2: 2000
Log3: 2000
Total File Size: 4.12791967391968 GB

Starting Tasks...
Log1: 2/10/2020 8:36:22 PM
Finished: 2/10/2020 8:37:30 PM
Log2: 2/10/2020 8:36:22 PM
Finished: 2/10/2020 8:37:27 PM
Log3: 2/10/2020 8:36:22 PM
Finished: 2/10/2020 8:37:28 PM
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, as I said, I want to use Winrar, because I want the Archive date to equal the file date, and I want to delete the files after archiving. I also want this to be smart enough to not delete files that failed to archive. I dont see that logic above. (Winrar has that built in).  Before posting here, I was able to build a 2 line command to zip the files using the native Compress-Archive feature. It works fine, except for those 2 requirements, which is what lead me to post here. Matthew's answer is just what I needed.

Comment: You did write, *I'm not married to Winrar if I can achieve this another way* so assumed you'd try what comes built in to powershell. But if you found a way with winrar, and performance and compression is what you need, go with that

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I should have worded my original request better. Correct, I'm, not married to WinRar "IF I can achieve this another way" which was referencing the two points directly preceding that. (Set the archive date and time to match the zipped file date / time and also delete the original file ONLY if the zip actually succeeds) As far as I can tell neither seemed to be satisfied by this script. Compress-Archive itself is fine if the script were handling those other 2 requirements.